# Laravel 5 adding Many One To Many relationships

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many, laravel-5

I have a problem with storing multiple One to Many relationships value to the DB .

Migration:

```
Schema::create('articles', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug', 100)->unique();
        $table->LongText('body');
        $table->text('excerp');
        $table->integer('img_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('img_gal_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('published_at');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('img_gal_id')->references('id')->on('image_galleries');
        $table->foreign('img_id')->references('id')->on('images');
    });
```

Form

```
{!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
{!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-container']) !!}

{!! Form::label('images', 'Article Image') !!}
{!! Form::file('images[]', ['class' => 'form-container', 'multiple']) !!}

and so on....
```

Part of Article.php

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'user_id','slug', 'body', 'excerp','published_at', 'img_id', 'img_gal_id'];


     / **
     * Articles from a user.
     * One To Many Relasion
     * @var array
     */
    public function user()
    {

    return $this->BelongsTo('App\User');

    }
    /**
     * Main Image for article.
     * Many to One Relasion
     * @var array
     */
    public function Image()
    {

    return $this->BelongsTo('App\Image');

    }
```

Image

```
/**
*One to many relasionship with article entity 
*/
public function articles()
{

return $this->HasMany('App\Article');
}
```

Controller

```
public function store(CreateArticleRequest $request)
{
    $images = Input::file('images');
    $imgobj = new Image;

   // Imgprof = Upload the file and store it to db

    $imgobj-> Imgprof($images);
 // Uploaded img id :
    $Uploadedimgid = $imgobj->Getimgids();


    $article = \Auth::user()->articles()->create($request->all());
}
```

I am storing 2 obj to db (Image - imgobj  and Article)

I've managed to store users id to the db, but now how to store the value of $uploadedimgid to the same $article(to img_id)?

I tried to append image()->$imgobj but no success.

Thanks!

Comment: you might want to do 

`$article = \Auth::user()->articles()->create($request->all() + ['img_id'=> $Uploadedimgid]);`